# How to get Mustache/Handlebars in INtellij Idea 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just installed INtellij 14, I created a sample.handlebars file and it appears there is no "mustache" icon as I would expect if it were webstorm. I looked in plugins and there was no "Mustache/Handlebars" plugin. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

In your Settings > Plugins, select 'Browse Repositories'. Search for Handlebars/Mustache there. You will find it.